# How do I get the right "this" in an Array.map?

Tags: javascript

I assume there is some application of `call` or `apply` here but I'm not sure how to implement it.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oXmmzo

```
a = {
  foo: 'bar',
  things: [1, 2, 3],
  showFooForEach: function() {
    this.things.map(function(thing) {
      console.log(this.foo, thing);
    });
  }
}

a.showFooForEach();
```

Say I want to `map` an array, but in the function, I need access to the `this` to which `foo` belongs. The `function` of `map` creates a new `this` context, so I obviously need to coerse that context back in somehow,  but how do I do that while still having access to `thing`?

Comment: The accepted answer to this question should address your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback

Comment: Not really sure how this would go! When making a normal OOP project I might make say something like `var myself = this;` and then access `myself` from within the anonymous function.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Just realized I should have read the documentation for `Array.map()` more carefully. One simply needs to pass in the `this` value as the second parameter of `map()`

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VLggpX

```
a = {
  foo: 'bar',
  things: [1, 2, 3],
  showFooForEach: function() {
    this.things.map(function(thing) {
      console.log(this.foo, thing);
    }, this);
  }
}
a.showFooForEach();
```

In addition, understanding how `bind()`, `call()` and `apply()` work are a must for serious JavaScript developers. These allow us to skip silly assignments like

```
var self = this;
myItems.map(function(item) {
  self.itemArray.push(item);
});
```

with

```
myItems.map(function(item) {
  this.itemArray.push(item);
}.bind(this));
```

Answer (score 14):

**As of 2018, you could use an arrow function:**

```
a = {
  foo: 'bar',
  things: [1, 2, 3],
  showFooForEach: function() {
    this.things.map((thing) => {
      console.log(this.foo, thing);
    });
  }
}

a.showFooForEach();
```

You could use `bind()` it to your context.

```
a = {
  foo: 'bar',
  things: [1, 2, 3],
  showFooForEach: function() {
    this.things.map(function(thing) {
      console.log(this.foo, thing);
    }.bind(this));
  }
}

a.showFooForEach();
```

That's because of JS lexical scope

From MDN:

> The bind() method creates a new function that, when called, has its
>   this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of
>   arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

And here: http://javascriptissexy.com/javascript-apply-call-and-bind-methods-are-essential-for-javascript-professionals/

Also, `map()` does accept a second parameter as "this"

```
a = {
  foo: 'bar',
  things: [1, 2, 3],
  showFooForEach: function() {
    this.things.map(function(thing) {
      console.log(this.foo, thing);
    }, this);
  }
}

a.showFooForEach();
```

From MDN `map()` documentation:

> **Parameters**
>
> **callback** Function that produces an element of the new Array
>
> **thisArg** *Optional*. Value to use as this when executing callback.

Further reading: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

**Short advice**

> **PS.:** Array.map is usually called when you want to do something with
>   your array, for example adding 10 to each item, or something like
>   that... Since the Array.map returns a new array. If you're only using
>   console.log or something that wont affect the array itself you could
>   just use a Array.forEach call instead

Answer (score 9):

There are three ways:

**An plain-old variable**

One that doesn't have the special oddness of `this`:

```
var self = this;
this.things.map(function(thing) {
  console.log(self.foo, thing);
});
```

**Function.prototype.bind**

```
this.things.map(function(thing) {
  console.log(this.foo, thing);
}.bind(this));
```

**Use the second parameter of Array.prototype.map**

The (optional) second parameter is the context that the inner function is called with.

```
this.things.map(function(thing) {
  console.log(this.foo, thing);
}, this);
```

---

The first two ways are generic ways of dealing with `this`; the third is specific to `map`, `filter`, `forEach`.

Comment: Thanks for adding helpful context around each solution.

Answer (score 7):

Nothing complex needed! `map` takes a second param of `thisArg`, so you just pass it in with the function you want to invoke on each item:

```
a = {
  foo: 'bar',
  things: [1, 2, 3],
  showFooForEach: function() {
    this.things.map(function(thing) {
      console.log(this.foo, thing);
    }, this);
  }
}

a.showFooForEach();
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 3):

map allows a second argument called "thisArg" so you just use that like so:

```
showFooForEach: function() {
    this.things.map(function(thing) {
      console.log(this.foo, thing);
    },this);
```