# TypeError: can't convert undefined to object -- without undefined or object

Tags: javascript

Consider the code

```
const arr = [];
[1].map(arr.push)
```

This gives `TypeError: can't convert undefined to object` (on Firefox at least), but the nearly synonymous code

```
const arr = [];
[1].map(v => arr.push(v))
```

works fine.

As Thomas Babington Macaulay wrote in his commentary on the works of Erasmus, "What the...?"

Comment: why `map`? with no use of the return value?

Comment: @NinaScholz -- purely for the example.  I noticed the problem in the `.then()` of a promise, but it was easier to explain with a `map()`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get the right “this” in an Array.map?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31866390/1048572)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because `arr.push` is just a reference to a generic function not bound to `arr`.

Therefore, when called as a callback, it doesn't know on which array you want to push

```
var func = [].push;
func(123); // TypeError: can't convert undefined to object
```

This will work, but multiple arguments will be passed to `push`, which you probably don't want

```
const arr = [];
[1, "a"].map(arr.push.bind(arr)); // [ 3, 6 ]
arr; /* [  1,  0, [1, "a"],
         "a",  1, [1, "a"]  ] */
```

So just use your `[1].map(v => arr.push(v))`